# Identifying the class of data entries in a Linked List in Java

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

I have a populated Linked List which consists of 2 types of objects;
Job and Agent.

How can I iterate over the Linked List and identify the class of the entries?

The Linked List looks like such

```java
LinkedList pool = 
[[Agent{id='100', name='John'}], 
[Job{id='1', type='rewards', urgent='false'}], 
[Agent{id='101', name='Smith'}], 
[Job{id='2', type='bills', urgent='false'}], 
[Job{id='3', type='bills', urgent='true'}]]
```

The method which I am using currently returns a trivial answer - that class is LinkedList

```java
pool.forEach( temp -> {System.out.println(temp.getClass())});
```

output is "class java.util.LinkedList"

```java
Agent agent1 = new Agent();
Job job1 = new Job();
...

LinkedList pool = new LinkedList();

pool.add(agent1);
pool.add(job1);
pool.add(agent2);
pool.add(job2);
pool.add(job3);

pool.forEach( temp -> {
  // Pseudo Code for the desired result should be as such
  // if (temp.getClass = Agent) {System.out.println("Agent")}
  // else if (temp.getClass = Job) {System.out.println("Job")}
});
```

Expected results are described in the comments in the code above.

Thank you!

Comment: You should probably take a look at the instanceof keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use instanceof operator. It returns true if the object belongs to the class.

```
pool.forEach( temp -> {
     if(temp instanceof Agent) {
        System.out.println("Agent");
     }
     else if(temp instanceof Job) {
        System.out.println("Job");
     }
});
```

Comment: Correct. I would add an `else` to catch any unexpected type.